# Trouble persisting android spinner item on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am using two spinners. The items in second spinner gets populated dynamically based on the  selection of the item of first spinner. I have implemented **OnItemSelectedListener** and overridden **onItemSelected** to achieve this. I am also using SharedPreferences to persist certain data to take care of screen rotation. The trouble I am facing is that, everything works perfectly fine and as expected with android version 4.0 but the same code fails to work with above versions of android(4.1, 4.2, 4.3) and selected item of second spinner resets on screen rotation. What is driving me nuts is, with android version 4.0 things work perfectly fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: please post logcat to show the errors you are encountering

Comment: I dont get any error message. Its just that, the selected item of second spinner does not stay on screen rotation for versions 4.1 onwards.

Comment: then post the possible code unless we all will be guessing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, although is not perfect, more of a hook, if the screen is rotated , I am assuming the item selected item of first spinner and its index will be same(as i am dealing with natural numbers) so i am setting the data in the second spinner accordingly, otherwise creating a new spinner and setting the required data in that, in the onItemSelected listener of the first spinner. Not very clean, but works for me (for 4.0 and above versions).

```
                 if(firstSpinnerItemSelected != position || firstSpinnerItemSelected == 0){
                    firstSpinner.setSelection(secondSpinnerItemSelected, true);
                    ArrayAdapter secondAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                        context, R.layout.spinner_item, itemList);
                    secondSpinner.setAdapter(secondAdapter);
                }
                else{
                    secondSpinner.setSelection(secondSpinnerItemSelected, false);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what it could possibly have to do with versions > 4.0, however it might be a better idea to handle a configuration change by writing the data you want to keep into the bundle in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) and read it in onCreate(Bundle savedInstance).

Even though it won't "fix" the strange behavior you are seeing, but it should work...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is not a good idea to use SharedPreferences to persist that data. at the same time is not good idea to put a Spinner in the onSaveInstanceState() Bundle. Besides the fact that it is impossible, doing so would cause your new activity to hold onto a reference to that Spinner, which holds onto a reference to your old activity, which will cause a substantial memory leak.

Your Spinner's contents are set via some sort of Adapter. You should be making sure your new Activity can re-create that Adapter. Then, put either getItemSelectedId() or getItemSelectedPosition() in the Bundle, so you can restore the selection in the new Activity.

Comment: Overriding onPause() and onResume() suffices my need. When I say data, its just the item selected in the spinner(integer value). I am recreating adapter and attaching this with recreated spinner to ensure that I am not holding any reference of activity.

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement methods

```
onSaveInstaceState() // to save current selected items;
```

and

```
onRestoreInstanceState() // to select saved items.
```

Or you can add to your manifests activity tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

then your activity wont be recreated, and everything should be the same